# List of Weyl groups of compact connected Lie groups?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups

Where can I find, in one place, a list of all Weyl groups of all compact connected Lie groups (plus $O(n)$)? Ideally a description of the action on the maximal torus would also be included, but I won't insist on that.

This seems like the sort of basic information which should appear both on Wikipedia and in the back of any book on Lie groups. But the [closest thing I can find on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Lie_groups) includes several other bits of information about each of these groups, but not the Weyl group.

I've looked in the reference books I have available to me -- Fulton and Harris, Humphreys, Hall. But it appears that this information is not collected in one central place in any of these books (or else I just missed it).

I have to believe that such a list appears somewhere on the internet and in any number of books, so it would suffice to point me to one (but I'd really likely to be in one place, rather than having to go through separate chapters on orthogonal/symplectic/etc. groups and tabulate it myself). Alternatively, I'd bet any number of people could rattle off such a list off the top of their heads, thus creating such a list right here. If there's somebody who feels like doing that, I'd be happy to perform any "formatting chores" on the post to make it more readable.

Comment: May be [this WP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group#Weyl_groups)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, that gets me most of the way there! My remaining concerns are (1) I have to trust that the lettering conventions for Coxeter groups match up with those for Lie groups (that should be easy enough for me to verify somewhere) and (2) I'm a bit hazy things like how the Weyl group of $SO(n)$ relates to that of $O(n)$ or $Spin(n)$, and how the Weyl groups for complex groups relate to those for real groups. But I should really get straight on that stuff anyway.

Comment: Also, for the $D_n$ groups, I don't understand the notation for the group structure -- it's written "$C_2^{n-1} S_n$" -- I know what $C_2^{n-1}$ and $S_n$ are, but I don't know what juxtaposition means here. The reference for that column is to Wilson's _The Finite Simple Groups_, but he doesn't use that notation from what I see -- he just says that $D_n$ is index 2 in $B_n$...

Comment: You can think of those as $C_2^n S_n$ (or if you are familiar with wreath products $C_2\wr S_n$) is the group of signed permutations of coordinates. Or, $n\times n$ matrices such that there is a single $\pm1$ on every column and row together with $n-1$ zeros. The permutation tells us which row on each column has that non-zero entry, and the $C_2$ component is just the choice of $\pm1$. Then $C_2^{n-1}S_n$ is the index two subgroup where we place the constraint that there must be an even number of $-1$s.

Comment: IIRC with the complex groups (or more generally on the side of algebraic groups where we work over an algebraically closed field) we can arrange things (by selecting the preserved quadratic/bilinear form carefully) so that the Borel subgroup consists of upper triangular matrices, and the torus $T$ of diagonal matrices of the group. In those cases we can actually realize the Weyl group $N_G(T)/T$ pretty much as monomial matrices as above. I don't know what it looks like over real Lie groups for then we cannot arrange the positive root subgroups to be upper triangular.

Comment: I never more than glossed over what changes need to be done to fit the real Lie groups into this picture, and that is under a thick layer of dust now :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks, that's helpful. Actually one thing I was hoping to check was exactly which Weyl groups are wreath products of $S_n$. So it looks like $D_n$ is not quite, but at least it's still a semidirect product of $S_n$.